# RECaptcha with WTforms won't render

Tags: python, flask, recaptcha

I am using wtforms-recaptcha in order to get the Recaptcha to show.

```
pip install wtforms-recaptcha
```

I guided myself on this site to make the installation:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wtforms-recaptcha
```

The problem is that the recaptcha code is being echoed into the form. That is, I see the recaptcha's code on the form and not the recaptcha itself:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeCJvUSAAAAAAvqwJEueVdV0wyNLPtX6KWSTdXp"> </script> <noscript> <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LeCJvUSAAAAAAvqwJEueVdV0wyNLPtX6KWSTdXp" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br> <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"> </textarea> <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"> </noscript>
```

Form code on form.py:

```
from wtforms import PasswordField, StringField, validators, widgets
from wtforms.form import Form
from wtfrecaptcha.fields import RecaptchaField

class ContactForm(Form):
"""Enables the user to provide feedback."""

first_name = StringField('First Name', [
    validators.DataRequired()
])
last_name = StringField('Last Name', [
    validators.DataRequired()
])
captcha = RecaptchaField('Captcha', [], public_key='6LeCJvUSAAAAAAvqwJEueVdV0wyNLPtX6KWSTdXp', private_key='6LeCJvUSAAAAADcUvYyLv8kt9ARiTAluDGqHBumY', secure=True)
```

Calling the form from within the HTML:

```
                <form method="post">
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error has-feedback{% endif %}">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                {{ field.label(class="control-label") }}
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                                {{ field(class="form-control") }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% if field.errors %}
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <p class="help-block text-danger">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                {{ error }}
                            </p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ title }}</button>
            </form>
```

Route call code:

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
"""Display the contact page."""
form = ContactForm(request.form, captcha={'ip_address': request.remote_addr})
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    return "Thank you for contacting us."
return render_template(
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that WTForms-RECAPTCH does not return a `safe` string, but instead returns a unicode string.  The underlying issue needs to be fixed [here](https://bitbucket.org/excieve/wtforms-recaptcha/src/5b4399621c02ba418cbf73989088f3b110fdf77a/wtfrecaptcha/widgets.py?at=default) (by returning an instance of [`wtforms.widgets.core.HTMLString`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/1ac4dc4061a07867d63ed708bccba8f8adddbfab/wtforms/widgets/core.py#L51-73) or something else that provides an `__html__` method).

To work around the problem for now you should simply mark the field as `safe` in your template:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
    {{ field(class="form-control") | safe }}
</div>
```

Or, alternately, only mark the re-captcha field as safe:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
    {% if field.short_name == "captcha" %}
        {{ field(class="form-control") | safe }}
    {% else %}
        {{ field(class="form-control") }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

There is [a PR for this issue](https://bitbucket.org/excieve/wtforms-recaptcha/pull-request/4/mark-code-as-safe-html-to-avoid-escaping/diff) and this is fixed as of version 0.3.2

Comment: I never would've figured that out. Thanks alot!

Comment: Just released a new version on pypi that contains Sean's patch. Thanks again for noticing and fixing this!